# Execute multiple files at one go using a single bat file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, batch-file, execute

I am using a batch file to execute multiple sql files. 
So I have created a bat file like:

```
osql -S ServerName -U user -P password -d DBTest -i C:\SQLFILES\Test1.sql
pause
```

The above code executes a single file Test1.sql and if I need to execute the next file I have to again modify the bat file and change the file name.I am having 10 such sql files and I want to execute them one after another. Is there any way to do this at one go?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you could definitely do is give your BAT file a parameter (so you don't have to constantly change the BAT file contents...):

**ExecSQL.bat:**

```
osql -S ServerName -U user -P password -d DBTest -i %1
pause
```

and then you can call this batch file like this:

```
c:\> ExecSQL C:\SQLFILES\Test1.sql
```

and then

```
c:\> ExecSQL C:\SQLFILES\Test2.sql
```

and so forth